# Can i fill many spinners by same data using one method?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Hi i just think about spinners. I'm wondering, if i want to past same data to multiple spinners,can i do it in one method? I mean connect one adapter to many spinners,or i have to do it in onther methods? Here's the simple example. Let's say,that user have to select three week days from those spinners

```
public void first() {
    List<String> data = db.getBodyParts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}

public void second() {
    List<String> data = db.getBodyParts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    secondSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the duplicate code, just send the spinner as a **parameter** into your method like below:

```
public void fillSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
    List<String> data = db.getBodyParts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
```

Usage is like that:

```
fillSpinner(firstSpinner);
```

or

```
fillSpinner(secondSpinner);
```

**With this approach, you can use unlimited number of spinner without duplicated code.**

Comment: Thank you,but there's another issue. I want to set additionally String as an second input,but when i calling the AdapterView,i've got the error which says that String is had to be a final

Comment: @For_est_1 I do not know hot do you use the String you mentioned but you may try to define it as "final" or global.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
public void first() {
    List<String> data = db.getBodyParts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });

    secondSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
```